# Reaktor 5 - Weird Issue

Tags: reaktor

Anyone know the reason Reaktor 5 would keep making noise after the plug-in is deactivated/bypassed/even REMOVED as an insert...

It would seem like a buffer issue - but my buffer isnt infinitely long like this audio seems to be.

Hmmm... NI service center have an update for Reaktor in PT9?

I think I remember having this problem in 7.4 as well.

Cool program, but weird as all get out as an Instrument.

Comment: I like to idiot check my stuff and make sure I don't have some feedback loop on an aux or something. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @Utopia No. If the Instrument was completely removed from the chain and PT is not even playing and the sound is still going.... thats pretty cut and dry that its some kind of Reaktor issue.

Comment: I never had this kind of problem with Reaktor5 and Cubase/Live/AudioMulch. Could it be a PT issue?

Comment: I've had that problem with Reaktor4 and 5 espcially when it was hooked into a SSLaws9000 console.  Can't say that I'd be of any help with how to fix it though.  

Comment: Switch your firewire cable or hard drive. Call technical support.....